# Usage of has" or "have"

Tags: grammaticality

Please which comment is right:

The requested documents has been delivered
or
The requested documents have been delivered

Regards

Comment: Please consider our other site [ell.se] when asking really basic questions of English grammar.

Answer (score 1):

'Documents' is plural so here 'have been' sounds  more appropriate to me.

Comment: Welcome to our site. Note that an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to add more information, but as the Help Centre's guidance on [answer] says, "Not all questions can or should be answered here", so this question may not be worth the extra effort. :-)